# Adding a class to a parent div based on value in child div

Tags: jquery

I am new-ish to javascript and am attempting to add a class to a parent div (so I can utilize the Metafizzy Isotope sorting plugin) based on the range of values within a child div.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="product-list">
    <div class="hidden-price">Number Here</div>
</div>
<div class="product-list">
    <div class="hidden-price">Number Here</div>
</div>
<div class="product-list">
    <div class="hidden-price">Number Here</div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery function:

```
$('.hidden-price').each(function() {
if(this.text() < 5000) {
    $(this).closest('.product-list').addClass('Under5k');
}
else if (this.text() > 4999 && this.text() < 10000) {
    $(this).closest('.product-list').addClass('Under10k');
}
else {
    $(this).closest('.product-list').addClass('Over10k');
}
});
```

Here is a link to a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyccrane/gwYPw/

Thanks!

**Update:**

I incorrectly capitalized my classes on the jsFiddle. It was caught and has been updated as well as the correct answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text()` is a jQuery method, so you need to apply it to a jQuery object.
So instead of `this.text()`, you need to use `$(this).text()`.

You can achieve it using this function (A little cleaner version :P):

```
$('.hidden-price').each( function() {
    var size = $(this).text();
    if (size < 5000) {
        $(this).parent('.product-list').addClass('Under5k');
    } else if (size < 10000) {
        $(this).parent('.product-list').addClass('Under10k');
    } else {
        $(this).parent('.product-list').addClass('Over10k');
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gwYPw/18/)

Comment: This worked perfectly! I also had incorrectly coded my classes on the jsFiddle example.

Comment: @JeremyCrane: Oh yeah, forgot to look at the CSS. Updated the fiddle link :)

Answer (score 2):

[**Updated and Working JsFiddle code**](http://jsfiddle.net/gwYPw/17/)

**Working code**

```
$('.hidden-price').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() < 5000) {
                    $(this).parent('div').addClass('under5k');
                }
                else if ($(this).text() > 4999 && $(this).text() < 10000) {
                    $(this).parent('div').addClass('under10k');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).parent('div').addClass('over10k');
                }
});
```

Changes in your code

1. change function to Parent instead of closest
2. class name in smaller case "over10k"
3. Change "this.text()" to "$(this).text()"

Comment: Great catch @Pranay. This in combination with my incorrect usage of $(this).text() solved the problem.

Comment: @JeremyCrane - welcome..i updated answer with your mistake..dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if it worked for you..

Comment: @JeremyCrane- no issues do it when you got enought repo points..i.e. <=15

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
$('.hidden-price').each(function() {
if(this.text() < 5000) {
    $(this).parents('div:first').addClass('Under5k');
}
else if (this.text() > 4999 && this.text() < 10000) {
    $(this).parents('div:first').addClass('Under10k');
}
else {
    $(this).parents('div:first').addClass('Over10k');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually weren't that far off, you just need to remember that [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is a jquery method.  To access it, you have to attach `this` to a [jquery object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)(`$(this).etc` instead of `this.etc`).  The below code works fine for me:

```
$('.hidden-price').each(function() {
  if($(this).text() < 5000) {
          $(this).closest('.product-list').addClass('Under5k');
        }
        else if ($(this).text() > 4999 && $(this).text() < 10000) {
          $(this).closest('.product-list').addClass('Under10k');
        }
        else {
          $(this).closest('.product-list').addClass('Over10k');
        }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/gwYPw/12/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `parse` the text to `int` then you can compare the values:

```
$('.hidden-price').each(function () {
   if (parseInt($(this).text()) < 5000) {
        $(this).closest('.product-list').addClass('under5k');
   } else if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 4999 && parseInt($(this).text()) < 10000) {
        $(this).closest('.product-list').addClass('under10k');
   } else {
        $(this).closest('.product-list').addClass('over10k');
   }
});
```

checkout the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gwYPw/15/

Although your `js` is almost correct you just need one thing to amend and that is:

change `this` to `$(this)` and your `class initials are started with lowercase alphas`

```
$('.hidden-price').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() < 5000) {
          $(this).closest('.product-list').addClass('under5k');
         //^^^^^^------------------------------------^----------hope you get it.
    } else if ($(this).text() > 4999 && $(this).text() < 10000) {
         $(this).closest('.product-list').addClass('under10k');
    } else {
         $(this).closest('.product-list').addClass('over10k');
    }
});
```

Comment: Parsing is actually not required here.

Comment: Thanks @Jai. Actually the code that is being output from Shopify has already been parsed into an integer.

Comment: @JeremyCrane just updated the answer, your code is correct just needed some amends see the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simpler way to think of this is to start with adding a class to the `.product-list` elements and then deciding what class to add based on the contents inside.

```
$(".product-list").addClass(function () {
  var val = $(this).find(".hidden-price").text();
  if (val < 5000) {
    return "Under5k"
  }
  if (val < 10000) {
    return "Under10k"
  }
  return "Over10k";
});
```

Comment: Not a bad idea. I never thought to approach from that angle.